# PHP loop through arrays

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have an array ($array) that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => C
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => apple
        [1] => orange
        [2] => banana
    )

)
```

With CreateXML I want to take the array and create a XML document, but I'm having some problems. I'm using the foreach to get the first value from each array, because I want the [0]A [0]1 [0]apple to be in one element and so on..
With the code I have now it works for one element, how can I do it so I generates all the elements? Got lost in loops and just can't get it right.. Thanks for help!

```
public function CreateXML($array){

    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        $array2[] = $arr[0];
    }

    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

    $root = $xmlDoc->appendChild(
      $xmlDoc->createElement("rootelement"));

    $tag = $root->appendChild(
          $xmlDoc->createElement("element"));

    $tag->appendChild(
       $xmlDoc->createElement("Letter", $array2[0]));

    $tag->appendChild(
       $xmlDoc->createElement("Number", $array2[1]));

    $tag->appendChild(
       $xmlDoc->createElement("Fruit", $array2[2]));

    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

    $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;

    echo $xmlDoc->saveXML();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= count($array[0]); $i++) {
    $newArray[] = array($array[0][$i], $array[1][$i], $array[2][$i]);
}

// Some XML here

foreach($newArray as $row) {
    $tag->appendChild(
       $xmlDoc->createElement("Letter", $row[0]));

    $tag->appendChild(
       $xmlDoc->createElement("Number", $row[1]));

    $tag->appendChild(
       $xmlDoc->createElement("Fruit", $row[2]));
}

// Some more XML and output
```

That will work only if each of the sub arrays has exactly same number of elements